# Write data in separate columns in .csv file

Tags: c++, csv, hash

I'm having trouble with storing data in a csv file.

I'm hashing a text file that has ~15.500.000 lines and I have to make an Excel graph of frequency based on the hashes. The problem is that the maximum amount of rows that Excel supports is 1.048.576. So I was thinking that I could write the hashes in 15 columns, each one with 1.000.000 rows but I haven't figured out a way to solve this without comparing a bunch of numbers each time, because that would take up a lot of time since I'm dealing with this huge amount of numbers.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this? Maybe using a vector of vectors could work as well, I might try that right now. Thanks

Comment: hashes of what? *"graph of frequency"* implies that the same hashes are supposed to appear multiple times so the total number of hashes will be considerably lower than 15m

Comment: Just take the 15 first hashes, print them out on a single line, separated by comma. Then do the same with the next 15 hashes. And so on. And 15 million is not that much on a moderately modern computer, you can easily sort and arrange them however you want in memory before writing them out.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is that there is an N parameter, that acts as the upper limit for the hashes. If the hash value is bigger than N, then I adjust the hash by hash%N. My task is to run this for multiple Ns and make a conclusion based on the graphs and different Ns.
To VTT: This way there will be the exact amount of hashes as there are lines but they some of them would appear multiple times.
To Some programmer dude: I'll try this out. Do you reckon to use an array?